# Kinetic energy of two particles

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, reference-frames

I am not getting the expression of kinetic energy of two particles from ground frame in terms of the velocity of the center of mass,

please give the expression and explain how to arrive into the expression.

Comment: Please provide some more details on what your conceptual problem is.

Comment: some details are here  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/245208/

Comment: Is there anything in particular, that you don't understand? Of you don't gibt if more details, it's hatte to help you, already seem to have some derivation in mind, why not tell us where exactly you are having a problem? If we just reproduce the derivation here how would that help?

Answer (score 1):

There is no expression for the kinetic energy of two noncomoving particles in terms of the velocity of any one object, except that $T \le T_m+T_M$ for particles m, M. Kinetic energy is the scalar sum of scalar kinetic energy, while the velocity of the center of mass is the vector sum of vector momentum divided by the scalar sum of scalar mass.